# Files copying to different machine not happening from batch file executed from SQL Jobs

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to execute a batch file from SQL Server 2012 JObs with the following command

```
cmd.exe /c "D:\Batch Files\SQLDBBkupCopy.bat".
```

The objective of the batch file is to copy SQL DB backup to a different machine in the network. The Job successfully ran, but there was no files copied.

From the Jobs history I could able to see this error message:

> Executed as user: SLC\sqlagentservice. Invalid drive specification  0
>   File(s) copied.  Process Exit Code 0.  The step succeeded.

Here is my Batch file script:

```
***********Start******
@echo off
cls
echo.------------------------>>CopyLog.txt
echo.%Date% %Time%:- INITIATING FOLDERS......>>CopyLog.txt
set folder1="B:\SLCBackup\ForSymantec"
set folder2="\\testsvr\c$\SQLBKUP\SLCDBAREN"
echo.%Date% %Time%:- Initiation Complete.....>>CopyLog.txt
echo.%Date% %Time%:- Copying from %folder1% to %folder2% >>CopyLog.txt
xcopy /E /C /R /I /K /Y %folder1% %folder2%
echo.%Date% %Time%:- Complete...>>CopyLog.txt
*****End*********
```

However, if I try to copy in the same machine like:

```
set folder2="c:\test1"
```

it then works.

Comment: A see that the destiny is begin with '\' and not with '\\'. See if the service user of SQL Server has privileges at the destiny folder.

Comment: Hi Kris, thanks for the reply. But i have set this as 
"set folder2="\\testsvr\c$\SQLBKUP\SLCDBAREN"

Comment: I see, but the privileges at the destiny folder. Do you see if the SQL user services has it?

Comment: correct, the agent service user does not have permission to the destination machine... let me set and update you. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Kris, Your Suggestion worked, the agent service user did not have the right to copy. Thanks a lot

Comment: where did you change he agent service user rights?

Answer (score 1):

For any interaction with the Operation System, insure that the user services of SQL Server has the privileges

Comment: I have the similar issue now.I have given default network service as the service account.But i am not able to add it to the administor group